# R Lag Variable And Skip Value Between

Tags: r, dplyr, case, lag

```
DATA = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                  SCORE = c(6,4,8,10,9,0,2,3,3,7),
                  CLASS = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'),
                  WANT = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, -10, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I have DATA and wish to create 'WANT' which is calculate by:

For each STUDENT, find the SCORE where SCORE equals to SCORE(CLASS = C) - SCORE(CLASS = A)

```
EX: SCORE(STUDENT = 1, CLASS = C) - SCORE(STUDENT = 1, CLASS = A) = 8-6=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming at most one 'C' and 'A' `CLASS` per each 'STUDENT', just subset the 'SCORE' where the `CLASS` value is 'C', 'A', do the subtraction and assign the value only to position where CLASS is 'C' by making all other positions to `NA` (after grouping by 'STUDENT')

```
library(dplyr)
DATA <- DATA %>%
   group_by(STUDENT) %>% 
   mutate(WANT2 = (SCORE[CLASS == 'C'][1] - SCORE[CLASS == 'A'][1]) * 
       NA^(CLASS != "C")) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   STUDENT SCORE CLASS  WANT WANT2
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1     6 A        NA    NA
 2       1     4 B        NA    NA
 3       1     8 C         2     2
 4       2    10 A        NA    NA
 5       2     9 B        NA    NA
 6       2     0 C       -10   -10
 7       3     2 B        NA    NA
 8       3     3 C        NA    NA
 9       4     3 A        NA    NA
10       4     7 B        NA    NA
```

Comment: what if there are multiples 'A' and 'B' and 'C' for each student?

Comment: @bvowe If that is the case, you may use `pivot_wider` from the other solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with the data organized in a wider format first, then a longer format below. This solution works regardless of the order of the "CLASS" column (for instance, if there is one instance in which the CLASS order is CBA or BCA instead os ABC, this solution will work).

### Solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

wider <- DATA %>% select(-WANT) %>% 
  pivot_wider( names_from = "CLASS", values_from = "SCORE") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(WANT = C-A) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

### output `wider`

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  STUDENT     A     B     C  WANT
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     6     4     8     2
2       2    10     9     0   -10
3       3    NA     2     3    NA
4       4     3     7    NA    NA
```

If you really want like your output example, then we can reorganize the wider data this way:

### Reorganizing `wider` to long format

```
wider %>% 
  pivot_longer(A:C, values_to = "SCORE", names_to = "CLASS") %>% 
  relocate(WANT, .after = SCORE) %>% 
  mutate(WANT = if_else(CLASS == "C", WANT, NA_real_))
```

### Final Output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   STUDENT CLASS SCORE  WANT
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1 A         6    NA
 2       1 B         4    NA
 3       1 C         8     2
 4       2 A        10    NA
 5       2 B         9    NA
 6       2 C         0   -10
 7       3 A        NA    NA
 8       3 B         2    NA
 9       3 C         3    NA
10       4 A         3    NA
11       4 B         7    NA
12       4 C        NA    NA
```

Comment: is there a solution where we don't pivot wider ?

Comment: @bvowe, sure, @akrun provided another solution that didn't use `pivot_wider`

Comment: but that assumes there are no duplicates of 'A' or 'B' or 'C' but I have that

Comment: If there are duplicates, how would you like to treat them? create duplicated scores as well? use only the highest scores?

Comment: If there are duplicates they will be equal so it doesn't matter but I want to keep all the data

Comment: then @akrun solution still holds true. It works with duplicated `CLASS`